# BEP-20 token price in usd

Tags: erc-20, oracles, price

how can I get BEP-20 token usd price in smart contract, if it is in pair with BNB. Should i create an oracle?

Comment: is it on Ethereum or is this on Binance chain?

Comment: @thefett - Binance smart chain